Shift Register 4021 Scheme
out of pure interest and a month of free time, I decided to re-create the schematics of some things I had. One of them was the NES controller. I found the schematic on the Internet and decided to make it in Logisim, but, it uses Shift Register 4021.

After finding 4021 scheme on the Internet, I repeated it, except for one element - trigger. Since I'm new at this field and have no one to ask, I hope someone can tell me what this trigger is called:

I don't want to replace it with something similar (D-Trigger or Shift Register from Logisim), as I want to repeat the scheme as closely as possible. Below you can find the scheme for this trigger:

However, I don't know how to replicate it in Logisim, because I don't know how to create an element with labels “P” and “n”. I could not find a scheme or a description of how it works on the Internet. I hope you can help me find a scheme for the “PN block” or tell me what this trigger is called and how to create it in Logisim.
Thanks in advance.
Also, thats how my "trigger" looks like now:


These blocks are "transmission gates" ... https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/what-is-a-transmission-gate-analog-switch.html

An initial guess is that a “PN block” could be the PMOS and NMOS parts of a Transmission gate

Retro, transmission gates are found in Neemann's Digital program. It replaces Logisim quite well. You may want to look into it.

These blocks are transmission gates. In Logisim you find them in the "Wiring" folder.
What you call a "D-Trigger" is a positive-edge-triggered D flip-flop. Here it is built by two gated D latches. If you scroll down the linked Wikipedia page, you'll find that.
Another pair of transmission gates build a multiplexer for the D input and the P input.
This is the D flip-flop in Logisim. Please note the orientation of the gate control!

Logisim simulates a propagation time through all its elements. Therefore it is necessary to delay the non-inverted signals to the transmission gates. Otherwise you will experience simulation errors because of endless oscillation. Without the additional buffers, Logisim will switch off one transmission gate earlier than the other.
And this is the realized 4021 shift register:

